# Trying to understand over() and partition by

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the over and partition by functionality wrapped around my head. Here is an example that I just do not understand.

Here is the data I have:

```
SALESORDERID       ORDERDATE 
43894              08/01/2001 
43664              07/01/2001 
43911              08/01/2001 
43867              08/01/2001 
43877              08/01/2001 
44285              10/01/2001 
44501              11/01/2001 
43866              08/01/2001 
43895              08/01/2001 
43860              08/01/2001
```

When I run this query:

```
select Row_Number() over(partition by orderdate order by orderdate asc) 
    as Rownumber, salesorderid, orderdate
from test2
order by rownumber
```

Here are the results I get:

```
ROWNUMBER     SALESORDERID       ORDERDATE 
1             43664              07/01/2001 
1             43911              08/01/2001 
1             44109              09/01/2001 
1             44483              11/01/2001 
1             44285              10/01/2001 
2             43867              08/01/2001 
2             44501              11/01/2001 
3             43895              08/01/2001 
4             43894              08/01/2001 
5             43877              08/01/2001
```

Can someone explain this query to me. I am not new to SQL but windowing I have been struggling with and can't get my head wrapped around this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try ordering by order date, you'll see the results more easily

```
select Row_Number() over(partition by orderdate order by orderdate asc) 
    as Rownumber, salesorderid, orderdate
from test2
order by orderdate;
```

should give (i've added blank lines for clarity)

```
ROWNUMBER     SALESORDERID       ORDERDATE
1             43664              07/01/2001

1             43911              08/01/2001
2             43867              08/01/2001
3             43895              08/01/2001
4             43894              08/01/2001
5             43877              08/01/2001

1             44109              09/01/2001

1             44285              10/01/2001

1             44483              11/01/2001
2             44501              11/01/2001
```

You'll notice that the result is divided into 'partitions', each partition being the set of rows with identical orderdates.  That is what 'partition by orderdate' means.

Within a partition, the rows are ordered by orderdate, as per the second clause of '(partition by orderdate order by orderdate asc)'.   That isn't very useful, as all rows within a partition are going to have the same orderdate.  Because of that, the ordering of the rows within a partition is random.  Try ordering by salesorderid within the partition by clause to have a more reproducable result.

row_number() just returns the row's ordering within each partition

Comment: Also try SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(partition....) might be even clearer to you what it's doing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The partition clause is very powerful

Answer (score 14):

The `partition by orderdate` means that you're only comparing records to other records with the same `orderdate`. For example, of the five records with `orderdate = '08/01/2001'`, one will have `row_number() = 1`, one will have `row_number() = 2`, and so on.

The `order by orderdate asc` means that, within a partition, row-numbers are to be assigned in order of `orderdate`. In your example that has no effect, because you're already partitioning by `orderdate`, so all records within a partition will have the same `orderdate`. (It would be like writing `SELECT ... FROM t WHERE c = 6 ORDER BY c`: all selected records have the same value of `c`, so the `ORDER BY c` does nothing.) So, within a partition, the assignment of `row_number()` is arbitrary: each row will have a different number, but there are no guarantees about which row will have which number.