# Laravel select random rows from table based on another field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, random

There is a `words` table with 20000 records:

```
ID      name      rank
1       word1     3 
2       word2     5019 
3       word3     12334 
4       word4     23
5       word5     544
```

I want to select 400 words randomly from this table but with this condition :

**first 20 words:** select 20 words randomly from `words` with rank between 1 and 1000

**second 20 words:** select 20 words randomly from `words` with rank between 1000 and 2000

And so on...

Do I have to do this in 20 separate queries?  How? Is there a better way?

I am using laravel 5.4 and Mysql, Also a raw query suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Easy way

use a where clause to filter their rank, then use inRandomOrder() and take(20) to get 20 random ones.

```
Word::inRandomOrder()->where('rank', '>=', 1)->where('rank', '<=', 1000)->take(20);
```

## Hard way

To get them all in one query, you might try some funky logic like this:

first: define a view that returns the same table, but instead of rank, has categories, so category 1 for 1<=rank<1000, .... just to make the next step easier

now we can use partition by (see [Trying to understand over() and partition by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315070/trying-to-understand-over-and-partition-by)). Remember to order by RAND() inside the partition. Order the result of all this by rownumber.

Now we have a result that looks like this:

```
rownumber      name      category
1              word1     1 
1              word2     2 
1              word3     3 
1              word4     4 
...
2              word21    1 
2              word22    2 
2              word23    3 
2              word24    4 
...
20             word381   1 
20             word382   2 
20             word383   3 
20             word384   4 
...
```

By taking 400 of these tuples, we will have 20 random samples of each of the 20 categories.

Note-- ordering by RAND() can be slow, as explained here http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

**Edit**: turn out partition by is for sql server only. But you could do something similar in mysql

Comment: Thank you, then I have to put this in a `foreach` to take all 400 words, right?

Comment: oh, i misread your question, you want all the random words at once. But yes that will work.

Comment: I didn't get your funky logic! can you give me a pseudo code? or simple example